# The issue of reading multiple images from a folder in Matlab

Tags: windows, matlab

I have a set of images located in a folder and I'm trying to read these images and store their names in text file. Where the order of images is very important.

My code as follow:

```
imagefiles = dir('*jpg');
nfiles = length(imagefiles);    % Number of files found
%*******************
for ii=1:nfiles
    currentfilename = imagefiles(ii).name;
    % write the name in txt file
end
```

The images stored in the folder in the following sequence : `{1,2,3,4,100,110}`.

The problem that Matlab read and write the sequence of images as `{ 1,100,110,2,3,4}`. Which is not the correct order.

How can this be overcome?

Comment: Are the filenames actually `{ 1,100,110,2,3,4}. ` or is that just examples? It would be good if you then posted the real filenames.

Comment: You could remove the characters from the filenames and sort the numbers. You could also rename your files and add leading zeros.

Comment: @Steffen I was going to suggest the same thing. Extract the numbers from the filename and sort those.

Comment: yes, it's 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 4.jpg, 100.jpg .....etc ...

Comment: I tried to rename them all; and in windows it gives A (1).jpg , A (2). jpg, A (3).jpg, A (4).jpg, A (100). jpg ...etc ... but it gives the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `scanf` to find the number of the file. For that you have to create a format spec which shows how your file name is built. If it is a number, followed by `.jpg`, that would be: `'%d.jpg'`. 
You can call [`sscanf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html) (scan string) on the `name`'s of the files using `cellfun`:

```
imagefiles = dir('*jpg');
fileNo = cellfun(@(x)sscanf(x,'%d.jpg'),{imagefiles(:).name});
```

Then you sort `fileNo`, save the indexes of the sorted array and go through these indexes in the for-loop:

```
[~,ind] = sort(fileNo);
for ii=ind
    currentfilename = imagefiles(ii).name;
    % write the name in txt file
end
```